# Drop down list from database in PHP

Tags: php, database, drop-down-menu

I am trying to input my data from my database table venue into a drop down list and I am having some difficulty.

```
        <?php
        session_start();
        require_once("functions/User.cookies.php");

                require("functions/MySQL_class.php");
                $event = new MySQL_class();
                $event->Create();

                $event->Query("SELECT eid, `name`, date, `details`, vid, `mdetails`FROM event order by Date ");
                for($i=0; $i<$event->rows; $i++){
                    $event->Fetch($i);
            }


 ?>

        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
        <html>
<body>
    <div id="Createevent">

            <h1>create an event</h1>
            <form action="functions/C_create.php" method="post">
                <label>Event Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="inputname" class="text requiredField subject" value="" /><br/><br/>
                <label>Date</label>
                <input type="date" name="inputdate" class="text requiredField subject" value="" /><br/><br/>
                <label>Deatils</label>
                <input type="text" name="inputdetails" class="text requiredField subject" value="" /><br/><br/>
                <label>Venue</label>


                <select name"select" class"textfeilds" >
                    <option id="0"> -- select your venue --</option>
                    <?php

                require("functions/MySQL_class.php");
                $event = new MySQL_class();
                $event->Create();

                $event->Query("SELECT * FROM venue ");
                for($i=0; $i<$event->rows; $i++){
                    $event->Fetch($i);


                    ?>
                    <option id="<?php echo $event->Create['vid']; ?> "><?php echo $event->Create['name'] ?></option>


                    <?php   } ?>
                </select>   

                <input name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="button big red" type="submit"/>
            </form>
</div>
```

Comment: When the question form said you should add more details, it really meant that you should add more details. It usually helps to explain what specifically the problem is, if there was an error message, how the current code misbehaves, and what else has been tried so far. "HELP Please" is also super redundant, and does **not** incite anyone.

Comment: im sorry im new to this website and i just cant get the data to show on the drop down list i tryed adding a photo but my account wont let me because i don't have enough points the error will be in the select table thing if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you want to populate dropdown from data fetch from database, so update your code like:

```
 <?php
  // try this 
  $event->Query("SELECT * FROM venue ");
  while($row = $event->Fetch()) {
    echo '<option id="'.$row['vid'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
 } 
?>
```

Comment: that worked thanks problem is now it is just a blank feild when i just the drop down and doesn't display the name of the veune is only a blank space the blank space is the same number as the amount of venues i have any ideas thanks :)